# What is this syntax of defining a method in a React component with ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

As you know we can use ES6 in React since 0.13. And I found below syntax to define an event handler:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleClickEvent = evt => {
    this.setState({value: evt.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClickEvent} />;
  }
}
```

By this syntax we don't need to use `this.handleClickEvent.bind(this)`. I've searched a lot but still didn't find out why `this` in the method `handleClickEvent` is in the correct scope. Anyone could help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not ES6, it's an experimental ES7 draft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using `=>` *arrow function*.,

> Arrow functions do not have their own this value. The value of this
>   inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope.

[`Arrow functions`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)

With not [`arrow functions`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/) you should you should set `this` to function by yourself

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClickEvent = this.handleClickEvent.bind(this);
    //                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  }

  handleClickEvent() {
    this.setState({value: evt.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClickEvent} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander , it makes sense. So arrow function doesn't have its own `this`. Even if use bind(someObj) it will not use that object as `this` value.